# Return value from parameter function in js

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to return the value of a callback function, as shown bellow. Not managing to understand how to make it work (implementation for explaining purposes only)

```
console.log( hasLogin() );

function hasLogin(){
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.session) {
        return true;
      } 
    else {
      return false;
  }
});

}
```

In practice, I want hasLogin() to return true is response.session exists/is true.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't - since `getLoginStatus` is designed to be asynchronous, the result is simply not available yet. The best strategy is to *stay asynchronous*:

```
function checkLogin(result_callback) {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         result_callback(!!response.session);
    }
}

check_login(function(result) {console.log(result);});
```

That's how it is usually done in JavaScript. Of course it forces you to rethink your code flow.

Comment: Yup, I've done something like this. My asynchronous call processes the returned data. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`getLoginStatus` is calling your anonymous function, and that function is returning true or false, not `hasLogin`. hasLogin is actually returning `undefined`. Since this is happening asynchronously, you'll need to do something like this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    console.log(response.session);
});
```

Asynchronous calls can be tricky to deal with.

Comment: sure, that's what I've told. What I need is to get hasLogin to return true or false as stated.

Comment: hasLogin is calling a method that runs asynchronously. There's no real good way to do what you want, that's just the nature of asynchronous calls. Facebook could be slammed and getLoginStatus could take seconds to return, you never know.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really do this, because `getLoginStatus` runs asynchronously that's why it provides callback function.

What you can do is:

```
function hasLogin(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            console.log("got session");
        } 
        else {
            console.log("got no session");
        }
    });
}
```